# Boot Failure: "nvme nvme1: Duplicate cntlid 0 with nvme0, rejecting" after installing Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: boot, initramfs, nvme

I wanted to install Ubuntu linux (**22.04.1 LTS**, kernel: **5.15.0-52-generic**) instead of Windows 11. Therefore, I followed Ubuntu official tutorial:

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

However, I face the following issue each time I boot the OS:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FiWc.jpg)

After doing some search, I understood that the issue could be because there are two NVME SSD with the same manufacturer's name and this caused the error.

To resolve the issue, I changed the mode to AHCI, but it still did not work. How to resolve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This appears to be [a known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1961439). There are some unofficial fixes for this, but it requires "kernel hacking" ... 

Comment: Thanks. Could you please send me some links to these unofficial fixes?

Comment: [Here there be dragons](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8733310.html?sid=31fa57e0d9ea1397c51383ec7b83c5a6). Be sure to read things thrice and adjust for your own hardware configuration. There is no copy/paste solution at this time ...